# How to create a xls file from base64 data in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, base64, decode, xls

I get a response that is a base64 string, i need to convert it to xls but i can't do it

This is what i have, the file is created, but at time of opening is corrupted

```js
const str = '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';
const contentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

const byteCharacters = atob(str);
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
 byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: contentType});
const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const anchor = document.createElement('a');

anchor.href = objectURL;
anchor.download = name;
anchor.click();

URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
```

As a test I tried with a image png and works correctly
From this i just change the str to another base64 string and the contentType to 'image/png'

```js
const str = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
const contentType='image/png'
```

Comment: are you sure content-type is correct for xls?

Comment: Yes, i use the same content-type to generate a normal xls and it works